# NSDocument presentedItemDidChange called every second

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdocument, nsfilecoordinator

I'm working on an `NSDocument` subclass. It represents a text file in a text editor.

I'm trying to use [the `NSFilePresenter` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/) to respond to changes made by other applications (i.e., if the user saves a change in TextEdit while the same file is open here).

My current implementation works like this…

I add a property for a file coordinator:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator;
```

I create it lazily:

```
- (NSFileCoordinator *) fileCoordinator {
    if (!_fileCoordinator) {
        [NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:self];
        _fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:self];
    }

    return _fileCoordinator;
}
```

When `presentedItemDidChange` is called, I reload the file from disk and display it:

```
- (void)presentedItemDidChange {
    [super presentedItemDidChange];

    NSLog(@"presentedItemDidChange was called");

    if (self.presentedItemURL.isFileURL && self.fileType) {
        NSError *coordinatorError = nil;

        [self.fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:self.presentedItemURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:&coordinatorError byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
            NSError *readError = nil;
            [self readFromURL:newURL ofType:self.fileType error:&readError];
            if (readError) NSLog(@"%@", readError);
        }];

        if (coordinatorError) NSLog(@"%@", coordinatorError);

        [self reloadString];
    }
}
```

This code works: when I save a file in TextEdit, the changes appear in my app.

However, once I save this file, `presentedItemDidChange` is called repeatedly (about once per second). After a few minutes, the app crashes due to a memory error. No errors are logged; the console looks basically like this:

```
2016-02-17 22:43:46.233 MacDown[66847:2470964] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:51.721 MacDown[66847:2470960] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:52.816 MacDown[66847:2471206] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:53.819 MacDown[66847:2470964] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:54.920 MacDown[66847:2471206] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:56.014 MacDown[66847:2470964] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:57.115 MacDown[66847:2471206] presentedItemDidChange was called
2016-02-17 22:43:58.117 MacDown[66847:2470964] presentedItemDidChange was called
```

This is my first time using these APIs, so I assume I'm making a simple mistake. If it matters, I'm running OS X 10.11.3 and Xcode 7.2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`presentedItemDidChange` will be called not only when the file contents was changed but also when the metadata of the file was changed.
And `[NSDocument -readFromData:ofType:error:]` overwrite the last opened date, one of the file metadata, of the file.

So, this is the reason why `presentedItemDidChange` was called repeatedly. If you want to handle updated files in `presentedItemDidChange`, you normally need to determine what was changed at first.

cf. [NSFilePresenter Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFilePresenter/presentedItemDidChange)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't need any of that. `[NSDocument -readFromData:ofType:error:]` is called automatically when the file changes, so I just update the UI with the new data when it's called. I mistakenly thought this method was only called once, during initialization.

(I'm still not sure why `presentedItemDidChange` was called repeatedly.)

Comment: Did you set anything so `readFromData:ofType:error:` is called? I tried to reproduce this but only `presentedItemDidChange` is called (I delegate to `super`, too). It's called once, though, not every second. I suspect this is something unrelated that's causing the changes.